# Пояснить метод add в java

Tags: jframe, java

Прошу помочь с пояснением сабжа.
На данный момент пытаюсь отрисовать простые линии на фрейме. Создаю класс paint, передаю параметр Graphics g. Тут все ок, а вот дальше, чтобы линии отобразились на фрейме (чел из телевизора сказал написать, но не объяснил, зачем), надо написать в main'e `f.add(new snakegame())`. <--- Собственно мне это и непонятно.

```
package snakegames.net;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class snakegame extends JPanel {

    public static final int SCALE = 32;                          //Размеры Окна
    public static final int WIDTH = 20;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 20;

    public snakegame ()
    {

    }

    public void  paint  (Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawLine(5, 10, 50, 60);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       //полное закрытие окна
        f.setResizable(false);                                  //изменение размера не разрешено
        f.setSize(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE);               //установка размерров
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);                          //спавнится по середине экрана
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.add(new snakegame());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Непосредственно на фрейме обычно не рисуют (хотя это и возможно). Фрейм представляет окно, контейнер для компонентов. Рисуют обычно на этих компонентах. В вашем случае таким компонентом является класс `snakegame`, унаследованный от `JPanel`. Строка `f.add(new snakegame());` осуществляет привязку компонента `snakegame` к окну `f`. Метод `paint` переопределяет метод из класса `JPanel`, реализуя вашу логику рисования на компоненте.

Вообще, для наглядности этот код стоило разделить на два класса. Первый (назовём его `App`) содержал бы лишь метод `main`, создающий окно `JFrame f = new JFrame();`, устанавливающий его основные параметры и привязывающий к нему панель, на которой вы будете рисовать. Второк класс (`snakegame extends JPanel`) содержал бы непосредственно логику рисования (метод `paint`).

Comment: Еще стоит добавить, дабы человек на запутывался изначально, - помечать переопределение метода аннотацией `@Override`, чтобы было сразу наглядно видно.